# Как я могу перевести значения в dict из модели, содержащей переменные двух типов, в строки?

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

У меня есть некоторый массив данных, в котором для начала я перевожу строковые значения дат в тип Date, а затем создаю словарь, где эти самые даты служат ключом. Но мне необходимо в качестве значений иметь не модель, из которой я эти даты достаю, а набор соответствующих строк (заголовков). Каким образом могу это реализовать?

```
    static var newModels = [NewNewsRecordModel]()
    static var sortedMassWithSections = [SectionModel]()
    static var models: [NewsRecordModel]

    func translate() {
        for model in Transducer.models {
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
            if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: model.publishedAt) {
                let newModel = NewNewsRecordModel(title: model.title, publishedAt: date)
                Transducer.newModels.append(newModel)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func sortingByDictionaryToMass() {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let dict = Dictionary(grouping: Transducer.newModels) { (model) -> Date in
            let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: model.publishedAt)
            let finalDate = calendar.date(from: components)
            return finalDate!
        }
        
        for element in dict {
            // Need to translate values from NewNewsRecordModel into String
            let sectionModel = SectionModel(sectionTitle: element.key, cell: element.value)
            Transducer.sortedMassWithSections.append(sectionModel)
            // Need to sort sortedMassWithSections by first element in two-dimensional array
        }
        
    }

struct NewNewsRecordModel {
    let title: String
    var publishedAt: Date
}

struct SectionModel {
    let sectionTitle: Date
    let cell: [NewNewsRecordModel]
}

struct NewsRecordModel {
    let title: String
    var publishedAt: String
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, необходимо было лишь при помощи метода map и замыкания обращаться к свойству *title* у модели следующим образом:

```
for element in dict {
            let sectionModel = SectionModel(
                sectionTitle: { () -> String in
                    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
                    return dateFormatter.string(from: element.key)
                }(),
                cell: element.value.map { $0.title }
            )
            Transducer.sortedMassWithSections.append(sectionModel)
        }
```

Так же был реализован перевод Date in String